# Mongoose how to return only the modified object in array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

This is the schema that I have:

```
const userSchema = new Schema({
   local: {
      email: {type: String, unique: true, lowercase: true, trim: true, required: true},
      password: {type: String, required: true},
   },
   items: [{
     siteName: {type: String, trim: true},
     link: {type: String, trim: true},
     color: {type: String, trim: true},
     createdAt: {type: Date, default: Date.now, select: false}
   }]
});
```

I have the query below, which updates an item based on the id provided in the URL and then I set `new:true` which returns the entire `items` array of objects, but I need it to only return the single object I updated inside this array.

```
User.findOneAndUpdate({"_id": req.user.id, "items._id": req.params.id}, {$set: {
    'items.$.siteName': req.body.siteName,
    'items.$.link': req.body.link,
    'items.$.color': req.body.color
  }}, {new: true}, (err, user) => { ... }
```

So my question is how do I go about only receiving the updated object inside the `items` array instead of all of its contents?

Comment: Have you tried using the [findOneAndUpdate method's projection parameter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/)? That would be the obvious way of altering which fields are returned.

Comment: You can also simplify your query to `User.findOneAndUpdate({ "_id": req.user.id, "items._id": req.params.id }, { "items.$" : req.body }, { new: true }....`

Comment: Thanks, tried searching for answers before asking, but I guess i didn't frame my question the right way.

Comment: I found that using the simplified query replaces the entire document matched, and so fields that didn't get set by req.body are removed, so I will have to use the longer version instead